# juju ceph-mon is in error state after servers reboot. hook failed: "config-changed"

Tags: juju, openstack, ceph

I have successfuly setuped openstack 10 days ago. Today I rebooted serves and got next:

```
ceph-mon/0                maintenance  executing  1/lxd/0  10.2.200.44 
hook failed: "config-changed"                       
ceph-mon/1                error        idle       3/lxd/0  10.2.200.49                        hook failed: "config-changed"
ceph-mon/2*               error        idle       2/lxd/1  10.2.200.47                        hook failed: "config-changed"
```

I tried to debug this issue and got that trace:

```
root@juju-b8f983-1-lxd-0:/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-ceph-mon-0/charm# ./hooks/config-changed 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./hooks/config-changed", line 725, in <module>
    hooks.execute(sys.argv)
  File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-ceph-mon-0/charm/hooks/charmhelpers/core/hookenv.py", line 798, in execute
    self._hooks[hook_name]()
  File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-ceph-mon-0/charm/hooks/charmhelpers/contrib/hardening/harden.py", line 79, in _harden_inner2
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "./hooks/config-changed", line 187, in config_changed
    check_for_upgrade()
  File "./hooks/config-changed", line 113, in check_for_upgrade
    ceph.pretty_print_upgrade_paths()))
  File "lib/ceph/utils.py", line 2162, in pretty_print_upgrade_paths
    for key, value in UPGRADE_PATHS.iteritems()]
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

Could you help me? What is cause of issue? Some python version mismatch? However, how it possible if all worked nice before servers reboot.

Hope on you help.

Answer (score 0):

A Solution was upgrade ceph-mon charm because of Python 3 compatibility patch was issued. It was simple:

```
juju upgrade-charm --force-units ceph-mon
juju resolved ceph-mon
```